# SQL incrementing limit

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @AbbrvCount INT    
DECLARE @Abbreviation NVARCHAR(50)

SET @Abbreviation = 'PHMY'
SET @AbbrvCount = (2+ LEN(@Abbreviation)+ 1)    

DECLARE @CDCode NVARCHAR(50)

SET @CDCode = (SELECT CONCAT('CD', @Abbreviation, ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(CashierDepositCode, @AbbrvCount, 50 - @AbbrvCount)
               FROM CashierDepositSlips
               WHERE SUBSTRING(CashierDepositCode, 3, LEN(@Abbreviation)) = @Abbreviation
               ORDER BY CashierDepositCode DESC) + 1, '1')))
```

I'm am having problem when my `@CDCode` reaches `"CDPHMY10"`, it doesn't increment any more. Help would be appreciated. I want to increment it to `"CDPHMY11"` and so on..  Thanks

Comment: Format the code in yout question. What do you expect as a result after CDPHMY10?

Comment: i need it to increment to CDPHMY11

Comment: this is not even a working query. You didn't declare the data type for `@Abbreviation `

Comment: omg im sorry, its supposed to be. DECLARE @Abbreviation  NVARCHAR(50)

Comment: SET @Abbreviation = 'PHMY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the numeric part then convert to integer before able to order by in the way you want

`STUFF(CashierDepositCode, 1, @AbbrvCount - 1, '')` this will extract the numeric portion of the Code. But the result is still in string. So if you order it, '10' will comes before `9`

Change to the following

```
SET @CDCode =   
    (
        SELECT CONCAT('CD', 
                      @Abbreviation, 
                      ISNULL(( SELECT TOP 1 STUFF(CashierDepositCode, 1, @AbbrvCount - 1, '')
                               FROM       CashierDepositSlips
                               WHERE      SUBSTRING(CashierDepositCode, 3, LEN(@Abbreviation)) = @Abbreviation
                               ORDER BY   CONVERT(INT, STUFF(CashierDepositCode, 1, @AbbrvCount - 1, '')) DESC) + 1, '1'))
    )
```

Also, if the prefix `CD` is fixed, then it will be better to change the `WHERE` to

```
WHERE CashierDepositCode LIKE 'CD' + @Abbreviation + '%'
```

Comment: omg! thank you so much sir! You're a big help. have a good day!

Comment: please accept the answer if it resolved your question